# Combinatorial question (Dividing 8 teachers among 4 schools)

Tags: combinatorics

This question is very confusing to me. 8 new teachers are to be divided among 4 schools. How many divisions are possible?

The answer given in the back of the book (Ross, A First Course in Probability, 8th Edition) is $4^8$.

So, it seems Ross is saying there are 4 possible schools assigned to teacher 1 and 4 possible schools assigned to teacher 2 and so on until we reach teacher 8. But I was thinking of it at first as a partition problem where we have $x_i$ representing the number of teachers given to school $i$ and so we have $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 8$$ which we would want all non-negative solutions for. In that case, my answer would be $$n+r-1 \choose r-1$$ where $n=8$ and $r=4$ which gives ${11 \choose 3} = 165$.

My other consideration was assigning teachers to schools instead of schools to teachers. This would give $8^4$ instead of the book's answer $4^8$.

I am really not clear on WHY the book's answer is THE right one. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are considering the teachers interchangeable.  You are only counting the different ways of assigning a number of teachers to each school without considering which teachers they are.  The book is considering the teachers distinct.  The book is assigning teachers to schools to get $4^8$.  As it says, each teacher has $4$ choices and you multiply them.  It would be $8^4$ if you assigned schools to teachers.  Each of $4$ schools would have $8$ choices of teacher.

Comment: What is it about the language of the question that should make us think the teachers should be distinct?

Comment: Just the fact that the teachers are people and people are different

Comment: Then why $4^8$ and not $8^4$? Is there a convention that either the balls/urns should be taken to be the bigger number?

Comment: @Salazar_3854708 You are missing the point of the question that you posted.  The question that you asked is (in effect) how can the stipulated answer of $4^8$ be explained.  The answer of Ross Millikan answers that narrow question.  This does not imply that your alternative interpretation of the problem is not reasonable or is not plausible.  It only implies that the stipulated answer can be reasonably explained.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Salazar_3854708 As for your suggestion that $8^4$ would also have to be a plausible answer, I disagree.  The only way to make $8^4$ a plausible answer is by assuming that each school has $8$ choices for which teacher will be assigned to the school.  This would require that each teacher be (potentially) simultaneously assigned to more than one school.  This is not the normal connotation of assigning teachers to schools, because teachers can not normally be in two places at once.

Comment: @user2661923 I could argue that 4^8 does exactly what forms the basis of your objection. You cannot normally assign multiple schools to teachers, can you?

Comment: @Salazar_3854708 The expression $4^8$ represents that each school has $8$ choices, which implies that two schools can choose the same teacher.  This implication conflicts with the *no two places at once* idea.  The expression $8^4$ represents that each teacher has $4$ choices, which implies that two teachers can be assigned to the same school.

Comment: @user2661923: I agree. The example I had in mind was of inanimate objects.